# Calling pipe() from a PairRDD and passing a Java Object to it

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a PairRDD like `JavaPairRDD<String, Graph>` where `Graph` is a Java object I created using

```
PairFunction<Row, String, Graph> pairFunction = new PairFunction<Row, String, Graph>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Tuple2<String, Graph> call(Row row) throws Exception {
                Integer parameter = row.getAs("foo");
                String otherParameter = row.getAs("bar");
                Graph graph = new Graph( parameter, otherParameter );

                String key = someKeyGenerator();
                return new Tuple2<String, Graph>( key, graph );
        }

};
```

Now I need to run an external program using `myPairRdd.pipe('external.sh')` but I think Spark will pass the `Graph` object to `external.sh` via stdin.

I need to access `Graph.parameter` and `Graph.otherParameter` inside `external.sh`.

How to manage this situation?

Comment: This is what my external program receive from pipe() : `(62,br.com.cmabreu.Graph@622804e5)`. Note the key (62) and what I supose to be the Graph object: `br.com.cmabreu.Graph@622804e5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !!

Just need to override the `toString()` method of my POJO (Graph) to expose the desirable attributes !!!

In this case:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.parameter + "," + this.otherParameter;
}
```

Now the output is:

`(62,foo,bar)`